# How do I get place the legend at the bottom of my chart and keep it vertical?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, livecharts

I'm currently trying to use the LiveCharts library in order to create a basic ChartPie.
https://lvcharts.com/docs/WPF/2.0.0-beta.700/samples.pies.basic

I want to keep the legend, but I want it at the bottom and I want the items to keep their vertical orientation.

The issue occurs when I change the `LegendPosition` from Right to Bottom. It does infact place the legend at the bottom but it changes the orientation to horizontal.

This is what I have

```
<Border CornerRadius="10"
        Background="White"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Margin="10">

    <lvc:PieChart Series="{Binding Series}"
                  Title="{Binding Title}"
                  LegendPosition="Bottom">
    </lvc:PieChart>

</Border>
```

And it's a problem because I want it to fit inside the current border which it doesn't since it's orientation is horizontal. 
How do I properly set the orientation to horizontal while keeping the legend at the bottom? 
[image]

Comment: there are lot of bugs again..even the sample described with the code is not functional..  and it misses the fact to use the xaml to modify the template of controls..

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says that only "the position, the font, the text size or the background color" can be changed.

I would recommend creating a custom version of the control as explained here: [Legends](https://lvcharts.com/docs/wpf/2.0.0-beta.700/CartesianChart.Legends)

Then for the label you can add a transform property and rotate it 90 degrees. (As explained here:
[How to: Apply Multiple Transforms to an Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-apply-multiple-transforms-to-an-object?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8))

```
// Create a transform to rotate the button
RotateTransform myRotateTransform = new RotateTransform();

// Set the rotation of the transform.
myRotateTransform.Angle = 90;

// Create a TransformGroup to contain the transforms and add the transform to it.
TransformGroup myTransformGroup = new TransformGroup();
myTransformGroup.Children.Add(myRotateTransform);

// Associate the transforms to the button.
label.RenderTransform = myTransformGroup;
```